# Issues with exec() on php running a shell script

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell

I'm trying to use a php script for executing a shell script. However I'm having some issues apparently with the web server.

I have a bash script called switch_audio.sh. It basically changes the active audio output of the system.

I also have a script.php that runs the code below:

```
<?php
    echo "It's working";
    exec("/var/www/html/switch_audio.sh");
?>
```

When I execute `php script.php` it's working fine. However, when I try to run it on the web browser  by `localhost/script.php` I just get as ouput the "echo" part.

I've already tried to:

1. remove 'exec()' from the disable functions in php.ini;
2. give permissions for everybody in every folder on this path from "/"      to the localhost folder;

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: apache might use a different php.ini to cli. have you checked apache's php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

You already said you allowed the shell function on your php.ini configuration but it seems it's not working yet... so maybe:

- You didn't restarted webserver service after changes
- You have somewhere other statement more restrictive... maybe `ini_set` in your php files.

As a reminder, be sure that you are doing well on your php.ini file, check it for this kind of statement:

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec
```

Maybe you can try instead of exec other similar php function like `shell_exec` to check if it works. Or maybe is working and not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: `exec()` returns a string, but you also have to output it to the user:

```
<?php
    echo "It's working";
    echo exec("/var/www/html/switch_audio.sh");
?>
```